# Stop Playing Video When I Close The Lightbox

Tags: wordpress, video, popup, modal-dialog, lightbox

I built a popup using this [article](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp) and it looks really good.

Here is what I did:

```
<button id="open-popup">Play</button>

<div id="popup-box" class="modal">

  <div class="popup-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>[vimeo shortcode]</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Here is the css

```
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.popup-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

And here is the JS

```
(function($) {          
$(document).ready(function(){

// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('popup-box');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("open-popup");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}

});
})(jQuery);
```

When I click on the button it's working perfectly, it's centered and looks really good.

The problem is that, when I close the popup the video audio is still playing in the background.

I would like the video to stop when I close the popup.

Any help will be amazing.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the Vimeo content thus stopping the audio completely. If not that, you would have to use Vimeo API to stop/pause/play the video.

Here a demonstration of how it can be done, adding an iFrame as HTML content for `#popup-box .popup-content` and then setting the HTML to an empty string to remove it.

```js
(function($) {          
    $(document).ready(function(){
   
         var iframe = '<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/213100067?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&badge=0" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>';
        
         // When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
         $("#open-popup").on('click', function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();
             $('#popup-box').show();
             $('#popup-box .popup-content').html(iframe);
         });
        
         // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
         $('#popup-box .close, #popup-box').on('click', function() {
            $('#popup-box').hide();
            $('#popup-box .popup-content').html('');
         });

    });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display:none;
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.popup-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="open-popup">Play</button>

<div id="popup-box" class="modal">
 <span class="close">&times;</span>
 <div class="popup-content">
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tweaked it a bit and I deleted var iframe = '<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/213100067?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&badge=0" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>'; from the JS file and placed the iframe here<div class="popup-content">
iframe
</div>
the problem is that after closing the video and trying to play it again, it doesnt show you the video... you need to refresh the page to watch it again. Any solution for that? Thank you

Comment: Sure shot. That was a proof of concept

Comment: The example here doesn't has this problem.... can't tell what modification you made that made it stop working...

Comment: There was a bug in my code, check the update: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/44059727/revisions

Comment: I can see your deleted answer.  The issue is: *you have to **remove** the iframe for the player to stop*. The `var iframe` is to store the HTMML for the iframe without rendering it. When we do `.html(iframe)` we bring it to existence.

Comment: Every time you click [play], jQuery picks the `var iframe` and populates the `<div>`. When closing the modal, the HTML for the iframe is deleted. Click [play] again, the var goes back to the div.

Comment: Ohh ok, so pretty much this code is good only for one video right? I can't use it with others unless I create the exact same code just with different iframe?

Comment: You can have `var iframe1 = '<iframe etc>'; var iframe2 = '<iframe etc>';`

Comment: Bummer... Well thank you for your help anyway. I appriciate it

Comment: How about var iframe = document.getElementById("videoID"); insted of var iframe = '<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/213100067?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&badge=0" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>';

??